# write a disk image with golang (direct drive access)

Tags: windows, go

Whether someone had experience with use of windows [direct drive access](https://support.microsoft.com/uk-ua/help/100027/info-direct-drive-access-under-win32) (raw device i/o) with Go?

My purpose to write down an image (raw dd copy) to the flash drive.
But all my attempts to make it by means of stdlib or [third-party](https://github.com/ncw/directio) libs have failed with `Access is denied` error (even with admin rights).

Maybe someone already has a recipe for right combinations of `os.FileMode`'s and file rights (for full access to `\\.\PhysicalDrive{N}`), or some alternative solution? I would be very grateful.